# How to deploy static files with Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-staticfiles

I've been trying to deploy the static .css files and stuff for a website my classmates and I have been doing. Right now we have kind of crap styling and stuff so we decided to use some code from Bootstrap to make it looks nice.

After editing my settings.py and doing python manage.py collectstatic, the static files were put into the static/ folder. Upon using the runserver command, none of the styling changes have been made. I've been looking on Google for a while but I have not discovered the solution.

I want to get it working on my local machine before I push it to PythonAnywhere.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for Dreadnaught project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = GOTCHA!

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'TTT'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Dreadnaught.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Dreadnaught.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Dreadnaught',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = ()

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (TEMPLATE_PATH,)
```

Comment: Here's a [guide to how to get static files working with django on pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoStaticFiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve your css and js files in production mode you must change Debug true to false.

`DEBUG=False`

For reference [STATIC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/#static-root-and-static-url)

Comment: I changed DEBUG to False and added localhost to my ALLOWED_HOSTS. I'm still not getting the updated styling.

Comment: @DrZoo Change back to DEBUG=TRUE. First above setting correct then you can access the static file in your browser by http://localhost:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css . Is that working ?

Comment: No. Does that mean I'm missing that file? If so, what does the file consist of? The error is: Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
'css/bootstrap.min.css' could not be found

Comment: @DrZoo Is that bootsrap file in your static folder ? can you make sure of that ?

Comment: No the file does not exist in the static folder.

Comment: So I talked to my classmate and I got the video he referenced all of this to. He missed a ton of steps that I've seen in the video. I'm going to watch it and I'll post again if I still have trouble. Thanks!